# Issue using drawString on transparent Graphics splashscreen

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen, graphics2d

`Graphics.drawString` doesn't appear to draw on a `SplashScreen` whose source is a PNG with transparent elements.

[image: splashscreen source with transparent elements]

It will, however, draw over the visible parts of the PNG if I move the text so that it overlays on the "WHO ARE" bit and / or the Pet Jam label at the bottom.

Enjoy my Loader class:

```
package view;

import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.SplashScreen;

import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Loader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        final SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
        final Graphics2D g;     
//      try {
//          GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
//          ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\data\\font\\PhantElemental.ttf")));
//      } catch (IOException | FontFormatException e) {
//           System.out.println("exception found");
//      }

        if(null != splash) {
            g = splash.createGraphics();
            renderSplashFrame(g, 0, splash);
            splash.update();            
            displayUI(g, splash);
        } else {
            g = null;
        }

    }

    private static void displayUI(final Graphics2D g, final SplashScreen splash) {      
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | 
                         InstantiationException | 
                         IllegalAccessException | 
                         UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
                    renderSplashFrame(g, i, splash);
                    splash.update();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Thread sleep exception, on outer splashscreen timer!");
                    }

                    if(i == 249) {
                        splash.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static void renderSplashFrame(Graphics2D g, int frame, SplashScreen splash) {
        final String[] comps = {
                "Initialising", 
                "Preparing logic", 
                "Preparing UI", 
                "Finalising"};
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
        g.fillRect(30, 150, 160, 50);
        g.setPaintMode();
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.setFont(new Font("Sans", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        g.drawString(comps[(frame / 63) % 4] + " . . ", 40, 160);
    }

    public class UnsupportedClassException extends Exception {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public UnsupportedClassException() {
            super();    
        }       
    }

}
```

You might need to play around with the target position for the text (and clearing rectangle). Obviously as this uses a splashscreen, you'll need to package and run unless there's some magic way of previewing this inside eclipse that I don't know of!

This approach has historically worked for me with non-transparent `SplashScreen` sources.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the splash screen will be the size of the png. You could have a look at SplashScreen#getBounds to see what the actual bounds of the splash screen is...

Comment: Oh, and you're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread...

Comment: I'm invoking a `Runnable` and deferring it, I'd imagine that doesn't block the EDT? As said, this isn't an issue in other implementations that don't feature a transparent PNG. The only change is the data in the PNG image. And aye, the `SplashScreen` is the size of the PNG (320 * 200 for the record), but that doesn't tell me anything I don't know.

Comment: In what context do you think the runnable is been executed within?

Comment: At the end of the active queue as per my understanding of how Runnable defers it, but I don't understand what impact this has on something that works fine if I simply swap out the image. Which I've just confirmed with a non-transparent image.

Comment: AND within the EDT, so NOTHING else can be processed, like new paint requests or other events, so blocking the EDT, other things could have been added to the queue after the Runnable was queued...

Comment: Okay, this is what I've learned...you can't paint to the transparent areas of the png.

Comment: I am aware of possible EDT blocks, I take great care to avoid them! Understandable advice though. Do you know why you can't paint to it? It seems to be a limitation of `SplashScreen` - the only alpha context available is that of the splash graphic used.

Comment: Without knowing "how" the splash screen actually works internally, know I don't, this just seems to be a limitation of the API